# Issue with fopen() with 301 redirect

Tags: php, file, redirect

I am attempting to connect to a URL that performs a 301 redirect.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=RHT+MSFT&f=sb2b3jk', 'r');

if ($fp === false) {
  die('Failed to open resource.');
}

while (!feof($fp)) {
  echo fgets($fp);
}

fclose($fp);
```

In PHP 5.3.15, this outputs:

```
$ php fopen.php 
"RHT",51.15,51.14,46.34,62.75
"MSFT",27.73,27.72,26.26,32.95
```

In PHP 5.4.12, this returns nothing (no errors, or warnings):

```
$ php fopen.php 
$
```

[`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is set to `On` in both environments.

I found the following [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62524). However, it was marked resolved in [PHP 5.4.12](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.12).

So, what am I missing?

Comment: It must be something in php.ini, your code is well executed for me on 5.4.7

Comment: Use `file_get_contents()` it leads to much readable code.

Comment: @Nabab, care to shed any light on what is *missing*. I'm also on PHP 5.4.12.

Comment: @powtac, I normally would. But I'm using `fgetcvs()` to read the result, so `fopen()` makes sense in this case.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary It's `fgetcsv()`! Ok, I see!

Comment: Can you `file_get_contents("http://www.google.com")` ?

Comment: It does not. So something else is missing because `allow_url_fopen => On`…

Comment: did you try with curl? just to see if you have the same problem